# How do I include Graphs/Plots/Charts in epub generated by bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown

I tried generating the epub for the bookdown demo, and the resulting epub did not contain the graphs and charts. I was able to see the graphs and charts in the generated PDF.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/
I ran bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'all') to generate the supported formats.

On expanding the epub and looking into the generated code I see that media folder is not inside the EPUB folder and the link for the image expects this. Changing `<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" alt="Here is a nice figure!" width="80%" src="media/file0.png" />`

to 
`<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" alt="Here is a nice figure!" width="80%" src="../media/file0.png" />`

resolves this.

Is there a setting to control the location of the media folder?

System information
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6 
RStudio Server 1.0.153
R: 3.4.2
MacTex

Comment: I don't have this problem on my Windows OS. Have you tried the default template by creating a bookdown project from the RStuido menu? Or using ctrl+shift+b hotkey to build the book instead of running render_book() function?

Comment: If you cross-post a question, please [mention it](https://yihui.name/en/2017/10/cross-posting/): https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/25b94a82bfb57bf85bfce9f3c6fe0c71d0cfc028) in the current development version of **bookdown**:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Yihui](https://github.com/yihui) indicated that the root cause could be pandoc 2 [bookdown-demo issue#21](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/issues/21), which turned out to be correct.

The problem was resolved after I uninstalled pandoc 2 and used pandoc 1.19 instead (both versions 1.19.2.1 and 1.19.2.4 worked).

Bookdown does not support pandoc 2 yet, but it looks like yihui has fixed this [bookdown issue #481](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/481).